# What is the difference between -fprofile-use and -fauto-profile?

Tags: c++, gcc

What is the difference between `-fprofile-use` and `-fauto-profile`?

Here's what the docs say:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

> -fprofile-use
>
> -fprofile-use=path
>
> Enable profile feedback-directed optimizations, and the following optimizations which are generally profitable only with profile feedback available: [...]
>
> If path is specified, GCC looks at the path to find the profile feedback data files. See -fprofile-dir.

and underneath that

> -fauto-profile
>
> -fauto-profile=path
>
> Enable sampling-based feedback-directed optimizations, and the following optimizations which are generally profitable only with profile feedback available: [...]
>
> path is the name of a file containing AutoFDO profile information. If omitted, it defaults to fbdata.afdo in the current directory.

(The list of optimizations in the `[...]` for `-fauto-profile` is longer.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I stumbled into this thread by a path I can't even remember and am learning this stuff as I go along. But I don't like seeing an unanswered question if I could learn something from it! So I got reading.

## Feedback-Directed Optimisation

As GCC say, both of these are modes of applying Feedback-Directed Optimisation. By running the program and *profiling* what it does, how it does it, how long it spends in which functions, etc. - we may facilitate extra, **directed optimisations** from the resulting data. Results from the profiler are 'fed forward' to the optimiser. Next, presumably, you can take your profile-optimised binary and profile *that*, then compile another FDO'd version, and so on... hence the **feedback** part of the name.

The real answer, the difference between these two switches, isn't very clearly documented, but it's available if we just need to look a little further.

## -fprofile-use

Firstly, your quote for `-fprofile-use` only really states that it requires **`-fprofile-generate`**, an option that isn't very well documented: the reference from `-use` just tells you to read the page you're already on, where in all cases, `-generate` is only mentioned but never defined. Useful!  *But!* We can refer to the answers to this question: [How to use profile guided optimizations in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366805/2757035)

As that answer states, and the piece of GCC's documentation in question here  *gently indicates*... `-fprofile-generate` causes **[instrumentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)** to be added to the output binary. As that page summarises, an instrumented executable has stuff added to facilitate extra checks or insights during its runtime.

(The other form of instrumentation I know - and the one I've used - is the compiler add-on library UBSan, which I use via [GCC's `-fsanitize=undefined` option](http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/10/16/gcc-undefined-behavior-sanitizer-ubsan/). This catches bits of Undefined Behaviour at runtime. GCC with this on has revealed UB I might've otherwise taken ages to find - and made me wonder how my programs ran at all! [Clang can use this library too](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html), and maybe other compilers.)

## -fauto-profile

In contrast, `-fauto-profile` is different. The key distinction is hinted, if not clearly, in the synopsis you quoted for it:

> `path` is the name of a file containing **AutoFDO** profile information.

This mode handles profiling and subsequent optimisations using AutoFDO. To Google we go: [AutoFDO](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoFDO) The first few lines don't explain this as succinctly as possible, and I think the best summary is buried rather far down the page:

> The major difference between AutoFDO [`-fauto-profile`] and FDO [`-fprofile-use`] is that **AutoFDO profiles on optimized binary instead of instrumented binary.** This makes it very different in handling cloned functions.

How does it do this? `-fauto-profile` requires you to provide profiling files written out by the Linux kernel's profiler, [Perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), converted to the AutoFDO format. Perf, rather than adding instrumentation, uses hardware features of the CPU and kernel-level features of the OS to profile various statistics about a program while it's running:

> `perf` is powerful: it can instrument CPU performance counters, tracepoints, kprobes, and uprobes (dynamic tracing). It is capable of lightweight profiling. [...] Performance counters are CPU hardware registers that count hardware events such as instructions executed, cache-misses suffered, or branches mispredicted. They form a basis for profiling applications to trace dynamic control flow and identify hotspots.

So, that lets it profile an optimised program, rather than an instrumented one. We might reasonably presume this is more representative of how your program would react in the real world - and so can facilitate gathering more useful profiling data and applying more effective optimisations as a result.

An example of how to do the legwork of tying all this together and getting `-fauto-profile` to do something with your program is summarised here: [Feedback directed optimization with GCC and Perf](https://blog.wnohang.net/index.php/2015/04/29/feedback-directed-optimization-with-gcc-and-perf/)

(Maybe now that I learned all this, I'll try these options out some day!)

Answer (score 4):

underscore_d gives an in-depth insight into the differences.

**Here is my take on it.**

Performing internal profiling by compiling initially with `-fprofile-generate`, which integrates the profiler into the binary for the performance data collection run. Execute the binary, for 10 minutes or whatever time you think covers enough activity for the profiler to record. Recompile again instead with `-fprofile-use` along with `-fprofile-correction` if it is a multi-threaded application. Internal profiler runs causes a significant performance hit (25% in my case) which does not reflect the real world non-profiler included binary behavior, so could result in less accurate profiling, but if all activity when running the profiler enabled binary scales with the performance penalty, I guess it should not matter.

Alternatively you can use the perf tool (more error prone and effort) which is specific to your kernel (may also need kernel built to support profiling, tracing etc) to create the profiling data. This could be considered, external profiling and has negligible impact on the application performance while being profiled. You run this on the binary that you compile normally. I cannot find any studies comparing the two.

```
perf record -e br_inst_retired:near_taken -b -o perf.data *your_program.unstripped -program -parameters*
```

then without stripping the binary, convert the profiling data into something GCC understands...

```
create_gcov --binary=your_program.unstripped --profile=perf.data --gcov=profile.afdo
```

Then recompile the application using `-fauto-profile`. Perf and AutoFDO/create_gcov version specific issues are known to exist. I referred to https://blog.wnohang.net/index.php/2015/04/29/feedback-directed-optimization-with-gcc-and-perf/ for detailed information on this alternative profiling method.

`-fprofile-use` and `-fauto-profile` both enable many optimization options by default, in my case the unwanted -funroll-loops which I knew had negative impact on performance in my application. If your the pedantic type, you can test option combinations by including the disabling counterpart in the compile flags, in my case -fno-unroll-loops.

Using internal profiling with my program after stripping the binary, it reduced the size by 25% (compared to original non-profiler stripped binary) however I only observed sub-percentile performance gains and the previous work output fluctuations that are reported by the program log (it's a crypto currency miner) were more erratic, instead of a gradual rising and lowering between peaks and troughs in hash rates like originally.

Overall, a stab in the dark.